# Rails3 How to get an action to do nothing under condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, controller

I have a view with a form. In one case (one value in the form is nil), I want the controller to do nothing.
But the controller wants to "render" something and is looking for a view matching the action of the submit button, but in that case, there is no view, since I want to do absolutely nothing and the page to remain as it is, WITHOUT re-execution of the page, which would be a waste of server power...
How can I translate this "do nothing" in rails?

Comment: Then you need to use Ajax.

Answer (score 2):

I can choose not to answer a question but controller can't, he must response once got a request, that's his job :)

An alternative is to use a client side Javascript validation to prevent the form to be submitted when invalid, say blank input.

Comment: I'm completely ignorant of javascript which I don't use. How would such a validation look like ?

Comment: A script will be generated from server side every time you load the form. A JS variable will be created according to model's validation rule. Then on client side the script prevent anything doesn't fit validation rule.